# rails g rspec:install << returns >> Could not find generator rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't get rSpec installed for Rails 3.

I'm running Ruby -v=1.8.7, Rails -v=3.0.0.beta4

So far I have..

```
 git clone git://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators.git lib/generators
```

My GemFile :

```
 group :test do
   gem 'rspec'
   gem 'rspec-rails'
   gem "factory_girl"
   gem 'cucumber-rails'
 end
```

I ran :

```
bundle install
```

Then :

```
rails g rspec:install
```

I get :

```
 Could not find generator rspec:install.
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hmm..I'm under the impression people might have solved this in other ways, but I just chose Rspec 2 for Rails 3 and it seems to have installed right.

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.7'
```

Answer (score 3):

You might need to list rspec-rails as part of the development group as well:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this same issue using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.3

I had to run `sudo gem update`, which updated bundler and then `rails generate rspec:install` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem I was having. Updating bundler fixed it.